# Determine an area of the region limited

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Let $g$ and $f$ be real functions, determine an area of the region limited by the $y$ axis by $g (x) = - | x-3 | +4$ and by the function $f (x) = \sqrt [3] {x ^ 3-x ^ 2}$

I tried to define the straight line  $r$ of the equation $y = mx + n $ the asymptote of $\sqrt [3] {x ^ 3-x ^ 2}$

Comment: First determine where the curves will intersect then calculate two integrals.

Comment: Is there a need to find equation of asymptote?